# Trying to delete a row from database(phpmyadmin) onclick

Tags: javascript, php, html

Trying to delete a row after clicking a delete button, but even there's no error, it doesn't work. At first I thought that it has to do with the if statements but nothing changed...Here's my delete code! Is there any other way? Thank you

```
<?php
                echo "<table>
                          <caption>Λίστα Χρηστών</caption>
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th scope='col'>Ιd</th>
                              <th scope='col'>Χρήστης</th>
                              <th scope='col'>Διαγραφή</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>";
                  $servername = "localhost";
                  $username = "root";
                  $password = "";
                  $db = "aws_chat";


                  // Create connection
                  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, 
                  $db);
                  // Check connection

                  $sql = "SELECT username,email,id FROM users WHERE 
                  user_type='user'";
                  $result = $conn->query($sql);

                  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                      // output data of each row

                  if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
                        $del = $_GET['del'];
                        //SQL query for deletion.
                        $sql_del = "DELETE * FROM users WHERE id=$del";
                    }
                      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                          echo "<tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td>".$row["id"]."</td>
                                      <td>".$row["username"] ."</td>
                                      <td><a href='delete_user.php?del= 
                      {$row['id']}'><input type='button' class='btn_del' 
                      value='Delete'/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                  <tfoot>

                                  </tfoot>";
                      }
                  } else {
                      echo "0 results";
                  }
                  echo "</table>";

                  ?>
            </center></div>
```

Comment: You set `$sql_del` but never execute it, you should also use prepared statements.

Comment: `DELETE * FROM users WHERE id=$del`  that is wrong  should be `DELETE  FROM users WHERE id=$del` also use prepared statements

Comment: after `$sql_del = "DELETE * FROM users WHERE id=$del";`   add  `$stmt= $conn->query($sql_del );`

Comment: Step one: Decide whether you want a link, or a button - you can not have both, nesting `input` into `a` is invalid HTML.

Comment: Thanks that worked! Didn't believe that it would be that :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
//SQL query for deletion.
$sql_del = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id='".$del."' ";
$conn->query($sql_del); // you missed this line which is required to delete the record from database
```

Comment: Why should OP try this code? What have you changed? Why does yours work?

Comment: which is $conn->query($sql_del);

Comment: @ParvejAlam before the update you had  `$sql_del = "DELETE * FROM users WHERE id=$del";` which is wrong

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code - such a long answer is really useless if the OP cannot spot the exact parts that make the difference

Answer (score -1):

change

```
DELETE * FROM users WHERE id=$del
```

to

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE id=$del
```

Comment: check isset($_GET['del']) that returns true when you click delete button!

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code, such that others can learn from it